# Color Management, Linux, Photoshop C2 via Wine

Tags: linux, adobe-photoshop, wine, color-profiles, icc

I am new to Color Management CMS, so doing it on Linux, and then throw Wine into the mix ... and I am a little lost.

However, I have Photoshop CS2 running okay with Crossover Professional on Ubuntu 9.10.  I have a Canon 450D (Rebel XSI) and I imagine I will be able to find a profile for my printer. I ordered a Huey Calibrator (yet to come).  I guess I will run into problems with Nvidia Twinview, but one calibrated monitor is good enough for now.

Am I going to be able to get color management from Camera -- Monitor -- Print?  Most specifically, when I get the Monitor profile loaded with something like xcalib, will Photoshop CS2 run through wine (crossover Pro) understand that? Will I need to select specific things / profiles in photoshop under the edit::Color Settings menu?

I found several pages on http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/ helpful, but am wondering about the Wine issue, and anything else anyone can do to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just done a little experiment with PS CS2 under wine (wine 1.1.42~winehq0~ubuntu~8.04-0ubuntu1 and Nvidia proprietary driver with twinview). I've got an NEC wide-gamut monitor (LCD 2690wuxi2) and I generated a profile for it using an X-rite Eye-one Display LT colorimeter with the Argyll tools - http://www.argyllcms.com/ . Incidentally, I first tried using a Pantone Huey colorimeter, and the results were bad - seems like the Huey works badly with wide-gamut monitors. The Nvidia proprietary driver doesn't currently allow for setting the video card LUTs for each monitor independently, so I'm applying the profile for my NEC to both monitors.

The experiment is basically this:

- load profile using `dispwin -L $profile`
- start Photoshop, open a test image containing saturated colours (especially 100% red), observe colours, and exit
- unload profile using `dispwin -U $profile`
- start Photoshop, open test image, observe colours again, and exit

With the profile loaded, the colours look good, and closely match those shown by other colour-managed apps (e.g. gimp, Firefox with CM enabled).
With the profile unloaded, the colours are wildly saturated, as you would expect to see when a wide-gamut monitor is displaying something intended for sRGB.

So it seems PS CS2 under wine uses the monitor profile installed by `dispwin`. I suspect it's using the X11  _ICC_PROFILE property that `dispwin` installs (use

```
xprop -root | fgrep _ICC
```

to see it) as `strace` on Photoshop revealed it wasn't opening any of my own .icc files.

Note that `dispwin -I` "installs" the profile (i.e. sets the X11 _ICC_PROFILE property) and also adjusts the video card LUTs (which I think is accomplished in the Windows world with the Adobe gamma loader).

Hope this helps